# /var/log/auth.log getting too big, records every minutes?

Tags: debian, logging

the file /var/log/auth.log in my debian 6 (with lamp) is getting pretty huge.

Here some lines:

```
Feb 18 17:26:01 nsxxxxxx CRON[13093]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 18 17:26:01 nsxxxxxx CRON[13093]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

for each minute of days there are these 2 lines. Can somone exaplain what's they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be some cron job running every minute. Check your crontab files at /etc/cron.d .

Comment: Or in `/etc/crontab` itself.

Comment: In /etc/cron.d there are 2 files `php5` and `mdadm`

Comment: What's the content of these files? When do this cron jobs start? Read " man 5 crontab ". A line starting with "*/1 * * * *   a_program" would run a_program every minute.